# Nginx serve static files for a Django app

Tags: django, web-services, nginx, deployment, docker

I have a Django app that I am trying to deploy. At this stage I cannot seem to serve up my static files from my Nginx container.

My project is set up like [here](https://realpython.com/blog/python/django-development-with-docker-compose-and-machine/://).

I have put my images into `{% static "minimal/theme/assets/img/pic.jpg"%}` directory.

File structure of my web app is:

```
.
├── Dockerfile
├── docker_django
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── apps
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── todo
│   │       ├── __init__.py
│   │       ├── admin.py
│   │       ├── fixtures
│   │       │   ├── foodprice.json
│   │       │   ├── location.json
│   │       │   └── menuitem.json
│   │       ├── forms.py
│   │       ├── models.py
│   │       ├── templates
│   │       │   ├── _base-original.html
│   │       │   ├── feedback_template.txt
│   │       │   ├── home-original.html
│   │       │   └── todo
│   │       │       ├── base-original.html
│   │       │       ├── base-template.html
│   │       │       ├── base.html
│   │       │       ├── detail.html
│   │       │       ├── email.html
│   │       │       ├── feedback.html
│   │       │       ├── home.html
│   │       │       ├── home_old.html
│   │       │       ├── location.html
│   │       │       ├── menu.html
│   │       │       ├── results.html
│   │       │       ├── test.html
│   │       │       └── thanks.html
│   │       ├── tests.py
│   │       ├── urls.py
│   │       └── views.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
├── manage.py
├── requirements.txt
└── static
    ├── main.css
    └── minimal
        └── theme
            ├── assets
            │   ├── css
            │   ├── img
            │   │   ├── pic1.jpg
            └── index.html
```

In my Nginx container I have a config file in the sites-enabled folder which looks like:

```
server {

listen 80;
server_name localhost;
charset utf-8;

location /static {
    alias /usr/src/app/static;
}

location / {
    proxy_pass http://web:8000;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}

}
```

Snippets of relevant sections of my settings.py are as follows:

```
BASE_DIR =     os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
print "base dir path", BASE_DIR
SITE_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
....
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
# STATICFILES_DIRS = (
#     os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
# )
# print(STATICFILES_DIRS)
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

production.yml is like:

```
web:
  restart: always
  build: ./web
  expose:
    - "8000"
  links:
    - postgres:postgres
    - redis:redis
  env_file: .env
  command: /usr/local/bin/gunicorn docker_django.wsgi:application -w 2 -b :8000

nginx:
  restart: always
  build: ./nginx/
  ports:
    - "80:80"
  volumes:
    - /www/static
  volumes_from:
    - web
  links:
    - web:web

postgres:
  restart: always
  image: postgres:latest
  ports:
    - "5432"
  volumes:
    - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data/

redis:
  restart: always
  image: redis:latest
  ports:
    - "6379"
  volumes:
    - redisdata:/data
```

When I run locally on my machine all the JavaScript and images that are in the static folders load and work perfectly. When I deploy into digital ocean the static files are not being served and I am stuck on how to get Nginx to serve my static files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to mount your folder `/usr/src/app/static` as volume in your web container. In that way, `ngnix` would be able to get access on it.

```
web:
  restart: always
  build: ./web
  expose:
    - "8000"
  volumes:
    - /usr/src/app/static
  links:
    - postgres:postgres
    - redis:redis
  env_file: .env
  command: /usr/local/bin/gunicorn docker_django.wsgi:application -w 2 -b :8000
```

In your `nginx` config you are telling to  nginx to serve static files from this directory `/usr/src/app/static`, but `nginx` container does not have it unless you linked it. You almost do it, you have `volumes_from: web` but `web` container is not mounting any volumes, because that you need to add `volumes: - /usr/src/app/static`

Answer (score 0):

There is no sense in using compose v1 syntax and, this is commonly done using data-volume-containers (appcode below). This ensures that you basically can design the folder-structure as you need on the data-volume-container and then mount that in all containers you will need.

Those are the changes you will need to do (docker composer v2 syntax)

```
version: '2'
  services:
    nginx:
      volumes_from:
        - appcode:ro

    web:
      volumes_from:
        - appcode:rw

    appcode:
      image: cogniteev/echo
      container_name: dwstorage
      command: echo 'Data Volume Container'
      volumes:
         - appcode:/www/static
volumes:
  appcode:
    driver: local
```

(not asked, but probably useful in this context)
A hint at this point, do not name you services like the daemons, but rather give them semantic names. So nginx can become httpd, web becomes app, and postgres becomes db.

If you replace nginx with apache, nothing needs to change in terms of inter-communication, same for postgresql vs percona or whatever.